# Pass content of div element to action with asp core 2.0 form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, helper

I have an asp core form that transfers data to my "Create" action. I have inputs with "asp-for" attribute to initialize specific columns in my db and i have a "Content" column which i want to initialize by fetching innerText from  element. So how can i send innerText at the time when i submit form and to send it all together to the action? And is it possible to create custom asp core tag that would fetch innerText? Thanks.

```
<form asp-action="Create">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="preview">
            <div id="result">

            </div>
            <div class="settings">
                <label><input type="button" id="myBtn" />Додати кнопку</label>
                @Html.Partial("_ModalBoxPartial")
                <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="auto-generate" />Auto-generate</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="save-as-practice" />Save for practice</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12" id="editor-wrapper" style="background-
            color:pink;">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="text" id="" name="module" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea id="translation" name="translation"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="KeyWords" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="KeyWords" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="KeyWords" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="CategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ShowCaseText" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ShowCaseText" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ShowCaseText" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ExprId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="ExprId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ExprId"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Image" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="submitBtn" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC, and I could say most MVCs frameworks, performs post using HTTP Posts (I know it sounds redundant). It means that it will only post values from **enabled** **input** elements. So, from the browser point of view, your div is not different from any other div.

One possible solution is just adding a hidden input with that very same value:

```
<input asp-for="Foo" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
```